# Android Honeycomb CheckBox against white background cannot be seen

Tags: android, checkbox, styles, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am putting a CheckBox against a white background. It looks fine on pre-Honeycomb devices but on Honeycomb, it seems that the graphic has partial transparency and is white, so when the checkbox is unticked, you cannot see it.

I tried using the `Theme.Holo.Light` style as follows:

```
<CheckBox android:text="" style="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:id="@+id/checkBoxWifiOnly" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This appears to have no effect. Am I typing the syntax wrongly?

Comment: If you eyeing for the custom checkbox then follow this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569412/customize-check-box-preference

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking to make it a custom checkbox, just to change it to the standard checkbox-on-white style - right now it's a checkbox-on-black so you can't see the box when unticked.

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the theme in a wrong way. Either apply **@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light** to the whole app/activity in the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#theme), or use **@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox** as the style of your CheckBox. Also note that the "Holo" theme is available only on Honeycomb and higher.

I think that you'll have to apply the theme to the whole app, if you want the checkbox to have a different background. The thing is, that **Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox** and **Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox** are the same and both extend the **Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox** style, which has the "button" variable set by the theme attribute **listChoiceIndicatorMultiple**. This attribute's value is, in fact, different for light and dark theme.

I'd suggest you to create your own theme in **values/themes.xml** file, like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAwesomeApp" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
...
</style>
```

and in **values-v11/themes.xml**, like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAwesomeApp" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
...
</style>
```

and then set it in your **AndroidManifest.xml**, like this:

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAwesomeApp" ... >
...
</application>
```

Maybe you should also read how the themes and styles work: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html