# Change box color of PreferenceCheckbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox, preference

How can I change the color of a PreferenceCheckbox? Currently it's black and I want something like green.

I tried it with `<item name="colorAccent">@color/toolbarColor</item>` but this does not have any effect on the PreferenceCheckbox.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [This answer should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569412/customize-check-box-preference). Or, you can create your own class extending [`CheckBoxPreference`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.java#CheckBoxPreference) and tweak the code that way. The [MaterialDialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/afollestad/materialdialogs/prefs/MaterialListPreference.java) source may give you ideas if you take this route.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the image for `Checkbox` and set `Checkbox` background....see the link for reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11464319/2987421)