# How to set Image in CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences, checkboxpreference

I want to add 4 image into a Check Box Preference in Preference Screen.
or
is it any way so that i can put 4 image in one line and at the end Check Box in Preference Screen.

Comment: see the below link for help it will give you idea-
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569412/customize-check-box-preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569412/customize-check-box-preference)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

custom_check.xml FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CheckBox 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+android:id/checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:button="@drawable/android_button"/>
```

Layout.

```
<CheckBoxPreference 
android:key="@string/Drop_Option"
android:title="XXXXX"
android:defaultValue="true"
android:widgetLayout="@layout/custom_check"/>
```